# Implementing a tree diagram

Tags: javascript, echarts

I would like to implement a tree diagram in the frontend.
In this tree diagram, the child nodes need to be arranged vertically, rather than horizontally.
[image]

[image]

I have tried using echarts to accomplish this, but the result is not satisfactory.

[image]

```
option = {
  series: [
    {
      type: 'tree',
      symbol: 'true',
      symbolSize: 12, 
      orient: 'vertical', 
        edgeShape: "polyline",
      label: {
        position: 'top',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        align: 'center'
      }, 
      data: [
        {
          name: 'Collector',
          children: [
            {
              name: 'COM1',
              children: [
                {
                  name: 'METEHDLPDXAP4'
                },
                {
                  name: 'METSLKTYDAK19'
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              name: 'COM2'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

If you have any good suggestions, please help me.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

take a look at https://gojs.net for such diagrams

Comment: OK, I'll try it, thank you！